# After cleaning a bean to cup machine can I reinsert the same filter?

Tags: cleaning, bean-to-cup

The Melitta Caffeo Gourmet bean to cup machine has built in cleaning and rescaling programmes. During these it is necessary to remove the Claris water filter.

Can I put the same filter back in? Or do I need to use a new one? Should I tell the machine via the care menu that I am removing/inserting the filter? Or just take it out without selecting remove or insert filter from that menu so it can remember how old the filter is?

Comment: I went ahead and removed the filter without telling the machine, ran the clean program and put the filter back (again without telling the machine. Some time later (approx the normal life of a filter from its first use) the machine asked for the filter to be changed. I think the machine would have assumed a new filter was being fitted if I had used the normal procedures from the care menu for removing and inserting the filter at clean-time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the machine you're using but it seems like the water filters have a lifetime counted in water litters so you don't have to change it everytime , just when it filtered the amount of water it's designed to.

I think you should try at least once to tell the machine you're removing the filter to see if it remembers how old the filter is but you should probably wait to be near to your filter end to do so because if it doesn't remember how old it is you can just change it for a new one. But you should try to tell the machine , you'd rather loose a filter than bug your machine !